# Can't Moderate Comments

Tags: facebook, comments

I've had my Facebook comments box working for a long time now, but I need to moderate some comments which contain personal information, and some comment spam.

Here's where the comments box is placed:

http://coaching.jamesfrancis.com/first-1000-online/

I've added the two correct Meta Properties ("app_id" and "admins") in the header, but the "Moderate" link still isn't appearing.

Also, the weird thing is that although I have many comments, none of them show up at:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments

... So I can't moderate them from there, either.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks!
- James.

Comment: Have you tried to feed your URL through the [Facebook URL Debugger?](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) It lets you know if any `og:tags` are missing and alerts you to any other problem there might be integrating your URL with the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/.)

Comment: Yeah - I've just done it. Everything comes back clear, with no errors... http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fcoaching.jamesfrancis.com%2Ffirst-1000-online%2F . Any help?

Comment: Bump... Can anyone help? It's getting pretty urgent now... @Lix

Comment: The problem is that we are not Facebook customer support so there is no additional information we can see that you can not.   Have you tried to [moderate the comments "inline"?](http://i.imgur.com/nkonp.png)

Comment: @Lix Yeah, that's understandable. I don't think Facebook had a customer support, anyway? Hence why I got directed here, haha. Also, the "moderate" links don't show up inline... :-( . In fact, I don't even get the choice between "Public Comments" and "Moderator View" as shown in your screenshot, even though I'm listed as the admin within the OG meta tags (and within the app itself on Facebook), and correctly logged into Facebook as that user...

Comment: Have you confirmed that the facebook UID you are using is correct? I had same problem due to using what I thought was the correct ID, but I was incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

In your meta tags, change "name" to "property" and make sure you include the other required meta tags for moderation to work. appart from the fb:admins one.

```
<meta **property**="og:url"                content="..." />
<meta **property**="og:type"               content="..." />
<meta **property**="og:title"              content="..." />
<meta **property**="og:description"        content="..." />
<meta **property**="og:image"              content="..." />
<meta **property**="og:admins"             content="..." />
```

Answer (score 0):

had the same issues, I fixed it by simply making the app public. To do that go to the facebook app admin page, click status and there is a switch to the right.

ok cheers, ewires